# Why graph factorization problems emphasize $k$-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question

When we study graph factorization a lot of emphasis is placed on $k$-factorable graphs, i.e. graphs in which the factors are all $k$-regular. Why is such a factorization more important then say factorization in complete graphs or bipartite graphs which appear to be more basic then $k$-regular graphs? Are these other kinds of factorizations too hard?